# Image generator missing positional argument for unet keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, generator, conv-neural-network

I keep getting the following error for below code when I try to train the model: `TypeError: fit_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'generator'`. For the life of me I can not figure out what is causing this error. x_train is an rgb image of shape (400, 256, 256, 3) and for y_train i have 10 output classes making it shape (400, 256, 256, 10). What is going wrong here?

If necessary the data can be downloaded with the following link:
https://www49.zippyshare.com/v/5pR3GPv3/file.html

```
import skimage
from skimage.io import imread, imshow, imread_collection, concatenate_images
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.morphology import label
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, merge, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Reshape, core, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon
import shapely.wkt
import shapely.affinity
from collections import defaultdict
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras import utils as np_utils
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
gen = ImageDataGenerator()
#Importing image and labels
labels = skimage.io.imread("ede_subset_293_wegen.tif")
images = skimage.io.imread("ede_subset_293_20180502_planetscope.tif")[...,:-1]


#scaling image
img_scaled = images / images.max()

#Make non-roads 0
labels[labels == 15] = 0

#Resizing image and mask and labels
img_scaled_resized = img_scaled[:6400, :6400 ]
print(img_scaled_resized.shape)
labels_resized = labels[:6400, :6400]
print(labels_resized.shape)

#splitting images
split_img = [
    np.split(array, 25, axis=0) 
    for array in np.split(img_scaled_resized, 25, axis=1)
]

split_img[-1][-1].shape

#splitting labels
split_labels = [
    np.split(array, 25, axis=0) 
    for array in np.split(labels_resized, 25, axis=1)
]

#Convert to np.array
split_labels = np.array(split_labels)
split_img = np.array(split_img)

train_images = np.reshape(split_img, (625, 256, 256, 3))
train_labels = np.reshape(split_labels, (625, 256, 256, 10))

train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels, 10)

#Create train test and val
x_train = train_images[:400,:,:,:]
x_val = train_images[400:500,:,:,:]
x_test = train_images[500:625,:,:,:]
y_train = train_labels[:400,:,:]
y_val = train_labels[400:500,:,:]
y_test = train_labels[500:625,:,:]

# Create image generator (credit to Ioannis Nasios)
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=5,
                     width_shift_range=0.1,
                     height_shift_range=0.1,
                     validation_split=0.2)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

seed = 1
batch_size = 100

def XYaugmentGenerator(X1, y, seed, batch_size):
    genX1 = gen.flow(X1, y, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
    genX2 = gen.flow(y, X1, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()

        yield X1i[0], X2i[0]


# Train model
Model.fit_generator(XYaugmentGenerator(x_train, y_train, seed, batch_size), steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(float(len(x_train)) / float(batch_size)),
                validation_data = XYaugmentGenerator(x_val, y_val,seed, batch_size), 
                validation_steps = np.ceil(float(len(x_val)) / float(batch_size))
, shuffle=True, epochs=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code, but considering your error:

> TypeError: fit_generator() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'generator'

this is caused because fit_generator call XYaugmentGenerator but no augmentation generator is called inside.

```
gen.flow(...
```

won't work because gen is not declared. You should either rename image_datagen to gen as:

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
```

or, replace gen with image_datagen

```
genX1 = image_datagen.flow(X1, y, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
genX2 = image_datagen.flow(y, X1, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
```